# Oracle sql developer logon denied

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I've been struggling with this problem using oracle db 19c and it's regarding establishing a connection with a created user with the needed privileges. I know that users are in the pluggable db so I created the user there. and added the command

```
GRANT connect,resource TO test;
```

and when I go to sqlDeveloper and create a new connection I insure you that the username and password are correct and the SID is set to orcl and everything is set up well but when I hit Test button it shows the error

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

what can possibly cause this problem?

Comment: "the SID is set to orcl..." - you should be connecting using the PDB service name, not the SID.

Comment: I thought it's just like establishing a connection using your system account"I am still a begginer". Thanks bro